# "Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before > then, they always return false. "

Tags: functions, errors, core

I'm getting the following error

> **Notice**:  is_tax was called **incorrectly**. 
>   Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before
>   then, they always return false. 
>  Please see Debugging in
>   WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version
>   3.1.0.) in **/home/username/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php** on
>   line **4161**

The weird part is that `is_tax`, is not mentioned once in my functions.php file:
https://gist.github.com/beckah/5eb004d9230f958667dedbc9d517d9c2

Nor is if found in the required option.php file:
https://gist.github.com/beckah/c38f6c1e7cc2b3bf3f2d762ac77f3d0c

What is causing this error and how can I alleviate it?

Comment: check your own functions.php in your theme/child theme folder or any custom code.

Comment: @rudtek checked in the theme's and child theme's functions.php file and nothin :/

Comment: did the error start when you installed a plugin or theme?  can you try changing themes and disabling plugins to see who the culprit is?

Comment: @rudtek it actually started when I restarted my php process so that http forwarded to https, im assuming it was probably an error that was laying dormant until everything was restarted

Comment: There's not enough info to test the your server setup here...I'd still suggest going through changing themes and disabling plugins to see who the culprit is.  You have to start somewhere.